# DatePickerDialog to setMaxDate and to maintain previously selected date

Tags: android, datepickerdialog

I am facing a weird problem i created an custom DatePickerDialog to maintain the previous selected date but unfortunately the setMaxDate date is set every time .when i click on the show the datepicker dialog :-(

```
public class CustomDatePickerDialog extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    int currentYear = -1, currentMonth = -1, currentDate = -1;
    public static String MONTH = "month";
    public static String YEAR = "year";
    public static String DAY = "day";
    private DatePickerListener listener;

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        currentYear = getArguments().getInt(YEAR);
        currentMonth = getArguments().getInt(MONTH);
        currentDate = getArguments().getInt(DAY);
        if (currentYear == -1) {
            currentYear = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        }
        if (currentMonth == -1) {
            currentMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        }
        if (currentDate == -1) {
            currentDate = calendar.get(Calendar.DATE);
        }
        DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, currentYear, currentMonth, currentDate);
        Date date = calendar.getTime();
        datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(date.getTime());
        return datePickerDialog;
    }

    public void setListener(DatePickerListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        currentYear = year;
        currentMonth = monthOfYear;
        currentDate = dayOfMonth;
        listener.onDateSet(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
    }

    public interface DatePickerListener {
        void onDateSet(int year, int month, int day);
    }
}
```

My OnClickListener:

```
    edtSubstrateChanged.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            openCalendarDailog(edtSubstrateChanged.getText().toString(), SUBSTRATE);
        }
    });
```

Method to open dailog:

```
   public void openCalendarDailog(String strDate, int clickedEditext) {
    int day = -1, month = -1, year = -1;
    if (!strDate.isEmpty()) {
        String[] strings = strDate.split("-");
        day = Integer.parseInt(strings[0]);
        month = Integer.parseInt(strings[1]);
        year = Integer.parseInt(strings[0]);
    }
    this.clickedEditext = clickedEditext;
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt(CustomDatePickerDialog.DAY, day);
    bundle.putInt(CustomDatePickerDialog.MONTH, month);
    bundle.putInt(CustomDatePickerDialog.YEAR, year);
    mCustomDatePickerDialog = new CustomDatePickerDialog();
    mCustomDatePickerDialog.setListener(this);
    mCustomDatePickerDialog.setArguments(bundle);
    mCustomDatePickerDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction(), "Date");
}
```

Comment: While showing your date picker fragment, you need to set the arguments again with the new values.

Comment: Are you doing a `setArguments()` on your fragment before showing it?

Comment: ya i did update to setArguments every time on the edit text .But if i remove the setMaxDate(date.getTime) it works correctly but using it set the current as the selected date appart from my previously selected date. @AbhishekJain

Comment: Can you post the code where you are launching this `CustomDatePickerDialog` ?

Comment: @AbhishekJain check the edit !!

Comment: @prasanthMurugan did you get any solution